# Why can't I access this variable's property with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax request just to check if I can access the title attribute that is inside an object that's automatically generated, so I can't know its name. So here's what I did:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=apple',
            success: function(data){
                //console.log(data['query']['pages']['856']['title']);
                for (const i in data['query']['pages']){
                    console.log(i['title']);
                }
            }
        })
```

However it gives me back "undefined" as response. If I leave only console.log(i) it shows everything right. Already tried i.title and nothing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: is `pages` an `array` or an `object`?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the object with dot? i.e. `data.query.pages` and `data.query.pages[i].title` ?

Comment: Maybe you get object in `JSON` format? Try to parse your data like this `JSON.parse(data)` before perform any operations with it

Comment: @Dmitry Why? It doesn't make any sense to convert an object to a string then back to the same object.

Comment: I agree with you, @Mike C

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` is the key in your object, and not the object itself.

If you want to access the object that `i` is it's key you should use:

```
data['query']['pages'][i]
```

Your code should look like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=apple',
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data['query']['pages']['856']['title']);
            for (const i in data['query']['pages']){
                console.log(data['query']['pages'][i]['title']);
            }
        }
    })
```

> Note that a better way to go over object's keys is using `Object.keys(obj)`

So I would use this code instead:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=apple',
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data['query']['pages']['856']['title']);
            Object.keys(data['query']['pages']).forEach(function(key) {
                console.log(data['query']['pages'][key]['title']);
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: Will be nice if the down-voter will explain. Thanks!

Comment: They almost never explain, you should be used to it.

Comment: I'm used to it. Doesn't mean I have to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try logging out `i`? You would see that `i` is a string and that's because [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) grabs the *keys* of an object, not the values. To get the values, you'll need to use the key on the original object.

```js
let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

for (let key in obj) {
  console.log(`Key: ${key}`);
  console.log(`Value: ${obj[key]}`);
}
```

So a rewritten version of your code might look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=apple',
  success: function(data) {
    // Accessing properties with a . is the same as
    // using ['key']
    for (let i in data.query.pages){
      console.log(data.query.pages[i].title);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data['query']['pages']` can be accessed as: `console.log(data['query']['pages'][i]['title'])`

Comment: `data['query']['pages']` is not array. It's an object. Double check.

Comment: `data['query']['pages']` is an object. OP was treating it as an array, hence the error. Your actual code solution will work, but it would give OP the wrong idea about why.